# Saving dictionary of images to local machine

Tags: python, image, dictionary, save

I have a dictionary of images and class labels:

```py
{
    'dog': ['dog1.jpg', 'dog2.jpg', 'dog3.jpg', ...],
    'cat': ['cat1.jpg', 'cat2.jpg', ...]
}
```

How do I save these locally on my windows machine in folders based on the dictionary keys ?

I.e. so that I have a 'dog' folder with all the dog images, a 'cat' folder with all cat images etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```py
import os

data = {
    "dog": ["dog1.jpg", "dog2.jpg", "dog3.jpg"],
    "cat": ["cat1.jpg", "cat2.jpg"]
}

for folder_name, images in data.items():
    dest_path = f"some_path/{folder_name}"
    os.mkdir(dest_path)
    for image in images:
        os.rename(f"some_path2/{image}", f"{dest_path}/{image}")
```

I assumed you have all the images in some directory and want to separate them by putting dog images into a dog directory etc.